# contact support: 899783842-5044 (859856306)

Tags: opportunity, update

opportunity update code was working fine, suddenly started getting error

"UNKNOWN_EXCEPTION: An unexpected error occurred. Please include this ErrorId if you contact support: 899783842-5044 (859856306)"

any help.

Comment: This is a GACK, and like the error message implies, you need to work with Salesforce's official customer support to resolve this. Remember that we're not an official part of Salesforce here. 99% of us are customers like yourself.

Comment: @DerekF, frankly, in the majority of cases Salesforce support is not the best (fastest, time saving) solution. By finding patterns in what produces the error and looking at all the involved processes (here eg. validation, automation, triggers, affected other objects etc.), a system admin or a developer can often avoid this happening. This certainly requires a lot of guesswork and experimentation, but it's often worth it.